# How to play more than one video at same time in Android?

Tags: android, android-video-player, openframeworks

I have an old project made in openframeworks and I want to port it to android. The project is all made with videos and I'm wondering if it's possible to play more than 1 video at same time on Android. In addition, i'm wondering if there is any way to show the videos with some kind of transparency.

Comment: try using AsyncTask in android

Comment: I think It is not possible for single video player, may be it is possible by multiple video players. @user2527917

Comment: Yeah, you would have to use multiple players, thumbnailed to be a small enough size to fit on the screen...